# What would be the best solution to avoid this infinite loop (useEffect)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I developed an application where I get an api (pokeAPI) with pokemons, and basically I have a global array with "myPokemons", so I want to display all my pokemons except the ones in that array, so I created the function "filterMyPokemons" that I filter the pokemons that should be displayed, and then I call this function in useEffect so that it is updated along with the page, putting a dependency array from the API list. The problem is that I now have an infinite loop that hurts the performance of the application.

```
import * as C from './styles';

import logo from '../../assets/pokelogo.png';
import { useContext, useState } from 'react';
import { useApi } from '../../hooks/useApi';
import { useEffect } from 'react';
import { useNavigate } from 'react-router-dom';


import Pokelist from '../../components/PokeList';

import CatchingPokemonIcon from '@mui/icons-material/CatchingPokemon';
import CatchContext from '../../context/Context';


const Homepage = () => {
    const api = useApi();
    const { showMyPokemons } = useContext(CatchContext);
    const navigate = useNavigate();

    const [pokemonList, setPokemonList] = useState([]);
    const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);
    const [text, setText] = useState('');

    const [myPokemonsList, setMyPokemonsList] = useState([]);
    const [pokemonListFiltered, setPokemonListFiltered] = useState([]);

    useEffect (() => { 
        const getAllPokemons = async () => {
            const myPokemons = await showMyPokemons();
            const pokemon = await api.getAllPokemon();
            setLoading(true);
            setPokemonList(pokemon);
            setMyPokemonsList(myPokemons);
            setLoading(false); 
        }
        filterMyPokemons();
        getAllPokemons();    
    }, [myPokemonsList]); 
 
    const filterMyPokemons = async () => {
        const filteredList = await pokemonList.filter(pokemons => !myPokemonsList.includes(pokemons.name))
        return setPokemonListFiltered(filteredList);
    };  

    const lowerSearch = text.toLocaleLowerCase(); 
 
    const filteredPokemons = pokemonListFiltered.filter(pokemon => pokemon
        .name.toLowerCase().includes(lowerSearch)    
    );

    const handleHome = () => {
        navigate('/')
    }

    const handleMyPokemons = () => {
        navigate('/mypokemons')
    }


  return (
    <C.Container>
        <C.Logo>
            <img src={logo} alt="" />
        </C.Logo>
        <C.Navbar>
            <input 
                type="text" 
                placeholder='Busque um pokémon...'
                onChange={(e) => setText(e.target.value)}
                value={text}
            />
        </C.Navbar>
        <C.Pokedatabase onClick={handleMyPokemons}>
            <button>Meus pokémons <i><CatchingPokemonIcon /></i></button>
        </C.Pokedatabase>
        <C.Pokelist>
            {filteredPokemons.map(pokemon => { 
                return (
                    <Pokelist 
                        name={pokemon.name}
                    />
                )
            })}
        </C.Pokelist>
    </C.Container>
  )
}

export default Homepage;
```

If I leave useEffect's dependency array empty, the items are not displayed, but if I leave any dependencies it causes an infinite loop. How to solve this problem?

Comment: why is `myPokemonsList` in the dependency array if you don't even use it in that `useEffect`? Can't you just remove it?

Comment: myPokemonList receives the global array with the names of pokemons from the context, as you can see in the const "myPokemons". I put it in useEffect so that it is rendered along with the page and that this information is sent to the "myPokemons" array which is consequently used by the function to filter the items

Comment: If I leave the dependency array empty simply my items are not rendered on the screen. What should I put in place of myPokemonList om dependency array?
 @FerToasted

Answer (score 1):

The problem comes with updating the `myPokemonsList` array within the `useEffect` hook that depends on that array.

```
useEffect (() => { 
        const getAllPokemons = async () => {
            const myPokemons = await showMyPokemons();
            const pokemon = await api.getAllPokemon();
            setLoading(true);
            setPokemonList(pokemon);
            setMyPokemonsList(myPokemons); // Here's the infinite loop
            setLoading(false); 
        }
        filterMyPokemons();
        getAllPokemons();    
    }, [myPokemonsList]); // Here's the infinite loop
```

You should have another use effect for updates on the `myPokemonList` in order to avoid updating and depending on the same list.

Comment: Another useEffect to store the array I get from context? which in this case I store in the state "myPokemonsList"

Comment: Could you show me what the code would look like?

Comment: I created my own state for pokemonList, but unfortunately without success